# Why does traceroute increment the destination port by 1 for each probe it sends?

Tags: linux, traceroute, tcpdump

I captured the packets sent by Traceroute using Tcpdump. Here is the screenshot Tcpdump below.

Why does traceroute increment the destination port by 1 for each probe it sends?

[image: Tcpdump]

Comment: Hi! I am a bit confused by the question. What are we supposed to be looking at in each screenshot? Also, the Stack Exchange sites really don’t work well if you post screenshots for text that can just be copied and pasted into the question. If possible, please remove the screenshots and add copy and pasted text formatted as `code` so we can more easily understand what your issue is.

Comment: I've edited the image. As you can see the port number of the destination (marked in red) are increasing by 1.

Comment: See https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/45408/traceroute-udp-port-question

Comment: Based on what @xenoid said, do some research on “UDP port incrementation.”

Answer (score 0):

This increment is done to keep track of the position of the devices between source and destination.
ie. UDP port number - 33434 gives us the position of the device.
CISCO IOS routers use UDP port 33434 by default and then increment the destination port number for every hop.

Comment: How would this work, and how is the Cisco reference related to the question?